# C#, Can I INSERT and DELETE from SQL Server table while reading it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, locking

Everything is quite in the title.

I'm reading the result of a `SqlCommand` (which is a join query of table1 and table2).

```
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, eve.Database))
   {
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //Performing some tasks
        }
   }
```

Actually in the "performing some tasks" part, I do some `INSERT` and `DELETE` on one of my join table (we will talk about table1 for example).

I'm currently intern in a company, the code is working well on small amount of data but my tutor is telling me that this is not a good idea because I may have some problems of reading and writing in my table because of SQL Server locks.

I would add that to trigger my INSERT and DELETE, I'm just opening a new connection (so I'm not using the main one) and I'm executing the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call.

```
using (SqlConnection cnx = Piivo.Utils.Open(Configuration))
{
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnx);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: So of course my question is : would some locks may happen in that particular case ? Or the "ExecuteNonQuery" may prevent the locking ?
And is it a good way of doing it ?

Comment: Getting into locking is a deep dive and is very much dependent on the queries, data, and settings involved.  That being said, modern RDBMS are very much made to handle concurrent reads/writes. When locking behavior is not what you want, then you will need to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: SQL Server **will** place locks - "shared" locks on the rows you `SELECT`, **exclusive** locks on those rows you insert or delete. But that works just fine, side-by-side, since SQL Server locks on the **row level** - individual rows get locked - no tables. As long as you don't do more than 5000 inserts and/or deletes on a single table in a single transaction - if you did, then SQL Server would *escalate* that lock to a table-level lock - and a table-level **exclusive** lock prevents *anything* from happening on that table

Comment: Alright but then If my SELECT operate on a join table (table1 and table2), in my case I may have to use the DELETE command on a row of the table1 wich I'm using from the SELECT. Up to now it doesn't seems that I've been locked on that delete, so I guess that a JOIN table will create it's own table ? Wich would allow me to DELETE what ever I want on table1 and table2 ?
For example here is the result of my select :
T1.1 - T1.2 - T1.3 - T2.1 - T2.2 - T2.3 (where T1.1 is the first column of the JOIN)
Would it be a problem to use the DELETE command on the column T1.1 (delete a row only in table1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can if and only if, the Select command has been completely executed, but you can't insert or delete on the same table, if the select command is still executing, since, they are both executing a SqlCommand in a specific table which needs a "single" open connection.

Answer (score 0):

Known the fact that I can't test this on huge data set right now, I'll have to secure myself from those locks.
I guess I'll have to store the result of my SELECT into a DataTable object, close my connection and then i'll be able to INSERT and DELETE safely. However I may have a lot of results in this SELECT, I'm not sure if this solution will be optimal but I don't have the choice.

Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: And one more thing is that Now, I have to use a cast to get a column of my DataTable to a specific variable : 
(Guid)row[1];

Instead of using intern method of SqlDataReader such as :
mySqlDataReader.getGuid(1);

I read yesterday than cast are not a good idea in term of optimisation...

Comment: After some perfs test, it doesn't seems to have an impact on the treatment time.